# Hash verification when pushing via SCP

Tags: scp

is there a simple way to verify file hash when uploading via SCP? I need a **bash shell script**, because the upload will be done automatically by cron. 
I use this command:

```
scp backup.tar.gz matoha@example.com:/home/matoha/backup/backup.tar.gz
```

I searched on the web and I have also looked in scp manual, but found nothing.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`md5sum` will do the job of giving you a hash.

Your script should

1. Call `md5sum` to get the hash
2. Copy the file
3. Call `md5sum` on the remote machine with `ssh`
4. Compare hash

Alternatively use `rsync` which does a whole file checksum on transfer

Comment: The second command is a typo and should be `md5sum` also. `mdsum5` doesn't exist. Incidentally, the ssh command would be something like `ssh user@192.168.2.18 'md5sum /path/on/remote'`.